# Prompt few days before SQL User's password expiration using VBScript

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, passwords

I am trying to create VBScript which will prompt me few days before my SQL user password expiration via email in SQL Server 2008.

I am able for the windows user but have no idea from where I can start for SQL user.

Please give your valuable suggestion.

Comment: There's no general way to take an SQL user and discover an email address related to it.